# admob: different ids for different activities of same app

Tags: android, admob

I have an android app with some activities. My question is:

Is that legal to use different AdMob ids for each because it will help me to monitor which activities are more frequently visited. Moreover, i also want different content of ads in each activity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*IANAL* but why would you use Admob to track which Activities are the most used in your app? Besides, since they issue just the one publisher ID for each app you configure on the Admob platform, I am sure they have a pretty good reason for it. Also, if you have, say, 20 Activities, you would essentially be registering 20 apps (non existent apps in the real sense). Not sure if that's a good idea either. But you might want a lawyer to clarify that for you if that is your primary concern and you have already decided that this is the best way to go about it.

Alternatively, if the only purpose is track which Activities are most used in your app, consider using the [Android Native Application Tracking SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/). You can download it off their website [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/resources) or from the SDK Manager from Eclipse. In The SDK Manager, it is under the *Extras* section titled *Google Analytics App Tracking SDK*

This is the Dev Guide that will help you get started with it: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by [*user908821*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908821/user908821) in his comment, you should also take a look at the [Analytics SDK Policy](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/policy).

Comment: Also, note the policies associated with using the SDK https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/policy

Comment: @user908821: Good one. I missed that one out. :-)

Comment: Thank you. I will consider that.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing illegal with using a different AdmobId for different spots within your app. And if each Activity has certain distinct characteristics that make it more useful to a certain portion of your users then it may help to segment traffic and provide better eCPM.

But I would not be doing it just to track users. Use an analytics tools to do that.